# List of files and Folder

Tags: php

actully i get the folder and files from perticular path but its doesnt returns the value what i want.

im expecting the return value like:-

```
[{"filename":"19_0_0_0_0_1.jpg","RFI":19},
{"filename":"19_0_0_0_0_2.jpg","RFI":19},
{"filename":"19_20005_1_0_0_1.jpg","RFI":19},
{"filename":"19_20005_1_0_0_2.jpg","RFI":19},
{"filename":"19_20005_1_429_0_1.jpg","RFI":19},
{"filename":"19_20005_1_429_0_2.jpg","RFI":19},
{"filename":"19_20005_1_429_1_1.jpg","RFI":19},
{"filename":"19_20005_1_429_1_2.jpg","RFI":19},
{"filename":"19_20027_1_0_0_1.jpg","RFI":19}]
```

and its give me like this output :

```
[{"filename":[{"filename":"19_0_0_0_0_1.jpg","RFI":19},
{"filename":"19_0_0_0_0_2.jpg","RFI":19},
{"filename":"19_20005_1_0_0_1.jpg","RFI":19},
{"filename":"19_20005_1_0_0_2.jpg","RFI":19},
{"filename":"19_20005_1_429_0_1.jpg","RFI":19},
{"filename":"19_20005_1_429_0_2.jpg","RFI":19},
{"filename":"19_20005_1_429_1_1.jpg","RFI":19},
{"filename":"19_20005_1_429_1_2.jpg","RFI":19},
{"filename":"19_20027_1_0_0_1.jpg","RFI":19}],"RFI":19}]
```

this is my code:

```
$ldir = "D:\php\EIL_App\RFIImages";
$data = listFolderFiles($ldir,19);

print json_encode($data);

function listFolderFiles($dir,$pRFI)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $fileInfo){
        if (!$fileInfo->isDot()){       
            $dataimg = $fileInfo->getFilename();
            if($fileInfo->getFilename() == $pRFI){
                if ($fileInfo->isDir()){
                    $dataimg = listFolderFiles($fileInfo->getPathname(),$pRFI);
                }
            array_push($result,array('filename'=>$dataimg,'RFI'=>$pRFI));
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Please give the suggestion what can i do???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to echo $dataimg.' '.$pRFI; before array_push and check the data flow, you will get some idea

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to complicate things

```
$prefix = 19;
$dir = "D:\php\EIL_App\RFIImages";
$data = glob("$prefix*.*",19); // it will give you array with all files matching pattern

// then you can do a loop

$arr = [];

foreach ($data as $filename) {
   $arr[] = ['filename' => $filename, 'prefix' => $prefix];
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

If you want to use iterator then use glob http://php.net/manual/en/globiterator.construct.php

Regarding your code

`if ($fileInfo->isDir())` this makes no sense because it will never go to this if. It's because before you check `if (!$fileInfo->isDot()){` and dot means either `.` or `..` which applies to directories. If you want to do it recursively then you can use

**Edit:**

I've noticed you do some recursion if so then probably it'd be better to use ResursiveIterator

```
function listFolderFiles($dir, $prefix) {
    $rii = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir));
    $files = new RegexIterator($rii, "^$prefix.*", RegexIterator::GET_MATCH); // note prefix cannot have characters that are special to regex or they should be escaped
    $arr = array();

    foreach($files as $file) {
        $arr[] = $file;
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php
http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.isdot.php